# Is there a sms authentication that works like 10minutemail?

Tags: tools, privacy, sms

I remember reading on this site a user recommending 10minutemail.com as a way to register or give email address to non-trusted websites.

Is there any similar site for disposable phone number for receiving a sms online?

I am trying to protect my phone number, while be able to still access websites without disclosing such information that I have reserved  for family & friends.

Comment: I have found http://receive-sms-online.com/, but it does not seem worthy to be compared with 10minutemail as the structure is not the same... (disposable & privates)

Comment: Milard, welcome to [security.se]. Please consider registering your account, in order to get full use of the site, including tracking your posts, receiving notifications, accruing reputation, and more... Please see the [FAQ] for more info.

Comment: @RickRhodes brilliant, that site can be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really quick or disposable, but getting a Google Voice account will also let you accept SMS messages to that account, and that's what I use for all of my sms verification. It gets spam SMS regularly.